# Fetch .pdf and .doc files into application that resides in iOS device

Tags: ios

I am working on one of the application where i have to show the list of files reside in iPhone i.e Doc, Pdf.From where i can select the file and upload it to server.

i have google the same but did't find any useful solution for fetching all kind of files in application.

Can anyone guide whether is it possible to achieve this in iOS platform?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access other app documents because each is sandboxed and one app cannot access another app document unless that app is explicitly sharing the documents.

> Users can also access documents from another app’s Documents
>   directory, if that app declares either the UISupportsDocumentBrowser
>   key, or both the UIFileSharingEnabled and
>   LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace keys in its Info.plist file.

If you mean access only permitted/shared documents then you can use [UIDocumentBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller)

Here is some tutorial's link to `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`
https://www.raywenderlich.com/131668/document-provider-tutorial
http://iosbucket.blogspot.in/2016/06/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-and.html